# "Haar-like" measure on $S_\omega$

Tags: measure-theory, permutations, infinite-combinatorics, haar-measure

Let $S_\omega$ be the collection of bijections $f:\omega\to \omega$. Endow $\omega$ with the discrete topology and let $S_\omega$ be endowed with the subspace topology of $\omega^\omega$, where $\omega^\omega$ carries the product topology.

**EDIT.** The following statement of mine from the original post is false:

> False statement: $(S_\omega, \circ)$ is a locally compact group and [so there is a Haar measure on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) $S_\omega$.

But: I would nevertheless like to know whether there is some "Haar-like" measure on $S_\omega$. Is there a constructive description of such a measure?

If yes: Let $M$ be the set of "finitely bounded permutations of $\omega$, that is, $$M=\{\pi \in S_\omega: \exists K\in\omega(\forall n\in \omega(|\pi(n)-n| < K))\}.$$ What is the Haar measure of $M$, and of $S_\omega \setminus M$?

Comment: This is not a locally compact group. (It has a basis of clopen neighborhoods each being homeomorphic to $S_\omega$ itself, which is not compact.)

Comment: Btw your subgroup $M$ is rather the group of "bounded displacement permutations" of $\omega$, and has also been referred to as "wobble group" of $\omega$ (viewed as metric space with the Euclidean topology). Another side historical remark is that this topology on $S_\omega$ was introduced by L. Onofri in 1928 (and rediscovered decades later).

Comment: Thanks - will correct. It would be interesting to know nevertheless whether there is a "Haar-like" measure on $S_\omega$ - what's your take on this?

Comment: There's no Haar measure on $S_\omega$. I don't know what you mean by "Haar-like".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever $G$ is a non locally compact Polish group, there does not exist any nonzero $\sigma$-finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $G$ such that all left-translates of $\mu$ are absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$. This is due to Weil; there is a nice proof in a 1946 paper of Oxtoby.

Comment: Do you have the title of the paper by Oxtoby you are referring to?

Comment: John C. Oxtoby, "Invariant measures in groups which are not locally compact", Trans. Amer.Math. Soc.60(1946), 215–237

Comment: I learnt of this proof in E. Glasner, B. Tsirelson, and B. Weiss,"The  automorphism  group  of  the  Gaussian  measure cannot  act  pointwise", Israel J. Math.148(2005) (where they attribute the argument in Oxtoby's paper to Ulam, somehow)

Comment: You're missing some assumption, since both the zero measure and the counting measure satisfy this requirement. Maybe you require that some neighborhood of $1_G$ has a positive finite measure?

Comment: An anonymous edit has been proposed to add the hypothesis "nonzero $\sigma$-finite".  I have rejected it in case it conflicts with the author's intention, but, if that is the correct hypothesis (and if perhaps the edit was proposed by the original author without being logged in), then perhaps leave a comment saying so.

Comment: [Oxtoby - Invariant measures in groups which are not locally compact](https://doi.org/10.2307/1990145); [Glasner, Tsirelson, and Weiss - The automorphism group of the Gaussian measure cannot act pointwise](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02775441).

Comment: @LSpice: Since the author is an unregistered account, it may very well be the author who suggested it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, [agreed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384752/haar-like-measure-on-s-omega/384767#comment980047_384767), and it seems very likely, but it's not obviously so.  That's why I mentioned that the author could post it as a comment and, as it were, "claim ownership" even if they couldn't log in.

Comment: Sorry, that was indeed me. I amended, using the account I used for this occasion (and which will disappear. For various reasons I no longer want to engage with MO with my "real" account, but from time to time I feel like I can point out something interesting. You'll find a few such contributions with silly nicknames over the years, not many). Sorry for wasting your time with the edit from my phone, and the careless first message.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to restrict your class of observables. What you *can* do for example is look at a uniformly chosen permutation of $N$ elements and only keep track of its cycle decomposition. You'll find that most points belong to cycles of length about $\alpha N$ for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$. If you then only keep track of cycle lengths, divide their length by $N$, and let $N \to \infty$, you *do* get a limiting distribution on the space of unordered partitions of $[0,1]$ called the Poisson-Dirichlet distribution. As usual, Terry has a nice write-up [on his blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/poisson-dirichlet-process/).